# Journal of Management citation style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm looking for a bibliographystyle (I'm using natbib with \citep and \citet) that can mimick the citation style of Journal of Management. I'm thinking it resembles authoryear, but I'm using bibtex, and there are still some differences. Ideally I can find an existing style...

It's a hanging style reference list. Original pdf with example [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/pb-assets/cmscontent/JOM/JOM_Style_Guide_revised_2017.pdf).

```
Amit, R., & Zott, C. 2001. Value creation in E-business. Strategic Management Journal, 22: 493-520.
Barney, J. 1991. Firm resources and sustained competitive advantage. Journal of Management, 17: 99-
    120.
Campion, M. A., Maertz, C. P., Palmer, D. K., & Tan, H. 1997. Rules for references: Suggested
    guidelines for choosing literary citations for research articles in applied psychology. Personnel
    Psychology, 50: 165-167.
Haleblian, J., Devers, C. E., McNamara, G., Carpenter, M. A., & Davison, R. B. 2009. Taking stock of
    what we know about mergers and acquisitions: A review and research agenda. Journal of
    Management, 35: 469-502.
Katz, D., & Kahn, R. L. 1978. The social psychology of organizations (2nd ed.). New York: Wiley.
Mathieu, J., Maynard, M. T., Rapp, T., & Gilson, L. 2008. Team effectiveness 1997-2007: A review of
    recent advancements and a glimpse into the future. Journal of Management, 34: 410-476.
```

Answer (score 0):

My best approximation:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```